# Bing maps infobox new line in description

Tags: bing-maps

For Bing Maps v8 I have an infobox and everything is working except I want the description to look like a list.

```
description = 'Status: '+status_label+'<br/>Site: '+site_label;
```

html is ignored inside of the infobox so < br/> does not work. As is the infobox shows 'Status: desc'. I also tried replacing < br/> with \n but that also did not work. Is there a way to make the description broken up so it is not one long string?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that the team is fixing. HTML should work in the infobox.

**Update (8/26/2016):** The team has now added support for HTML in infoboxes. This is currently available in the experimental branch of V8 and will be in the main release branch in a couple of weeks.

Comment: This still isn't the case as of right now. Everything at and after the HTML code still vanishes. Is this a bug that should be fixed anytime soon?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this on the standard Infobox right now. Try using the custom format http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#addCustomInfobox+JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br/>` in the description to create infoboxes with multiple lines.  However, although you can force a line break in this way in the title, it doesn't move the description down, so the second line in the title overlaps the first line in the description.